# post viewmodel using ajax to controller error

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

i am trying to bind list of questions using knock out template binding. I am success with getting data and template binding. but on next button click event i am trying to send viewmodel to controller but it is giving the null value in controller

My jquery code is like this

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "/Render/LoadSurveyQuestions?sg=" + getUrlVars()["g"] + "&stg=" +      getUrlVars()["sig"],
                success: function (result) {
                var lstQns = JSON.parse(result);
                viewmodel = ko.mapping.fromJS(lstQns);
                ko.applyBindings(viewmodel, document.getElementById("tblQuestions"));
             }
           });

        $("#btnNext").click(function () { 
              $.ajax({
                     async: true,
                     cache: false,
                     type: 'post',
                     url: "/Render/SaveSurveyQuestionOptions", 
                     data: ko.toJSON(viewmodel),
                     success: function (result) {
                        }
                      }); 
                 });
                });



             function getUrlVars() {
                     var vars = {};
                     var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
                        vars[key] = value;
                         });
                  return vars;
                         }
```

the controller is like this

```
        [HttpPost]
        public void SaveSurveyQuestionOptions(List<Question> listOfQuestions)
         {
             if (listOfQuestions.Count > 0)
             {
               Question objQuestion = new Question();
                osurveymanager.InsertQuestionAnswers(objQuestion); 

              }
         }  


Here i am getting listOfQuestions as null value
```

please help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are sending JSON string from the client side,

```
$("#btnNext").click(function () { 
    $.ajax({
     async: true,
     cache: false,
     type: 'post',
     url: "/Render/SaveSurveyQuestionOptions", 
     data: ko.toJSON(viewmodel),   //toJSON converts your viewModel to JSON string
     success: function (result) {
              }
 });
```

So you should accept it in a string variable on server side, so your controller action should be :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveSurveyQuestionOptions(string listOfQuestions)
    {
         var Questions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(listOfQuestions);
         //Now here Questions varibale contains the list Of question passed.. 
         //from the client side
    }
```

Try this and let me know if it helps!